# How to remove items in the "Open dictionary" window of MacOS Script Editor?

Tags: applescript, automator

There are some items in the dictionary that I can't find in the Window -> Resource Library. Actually they are all one application I created with Automator but for some reason appeared multiple times here. It looks annoying. Is there a way to delete them?
[image]